# Int object is not iterable, but I am using range function

Tags: python, int, iterable

I'm doing Monty Hall simulation and when I run these lines of code I get error message "int object is not iterable", but I am already using range function. Then later I tried it on a simpler code that essentially does the same and it worked smoothly.

```
def run_game(n):
    loss, win=0
    for i in range(1,n):
        switch(True)
        if nagrada==odabir_vrata:
            win+=1
        else:
            loss+=1
    vjerojatnost_dobitka=100*win/(win+loss)
    return vjerojatnost_dobitka

run_game(100)
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-829dad26acc9> in <module>
     10     return vjerojatnost_dobitka
     11 
---> 12 run_game(100)

<ipython-input-10-829dad26acc9> in run_game(n)
      1 def run_game(n):
----> 2     loss, win=0
      3     for i in range(1,n):
      4         switch(True)
      5         if nagrada==odabir_vrata:

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: note the arrow carefully. It's not happening in the for loop

Comment: `loss, win=0` will not work. Perhaps you mean `loss = win = 0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You meant to write `loss, win = 0, 0` or `loss = win = 0`.

With your code:

```
loss, win = 0
```

Python tries to unpack what you have on the right hand side, so it tries to iterate on it in order to get two values to assign to `loss` and `win`. But you have an `int` there, so it can't iterate on it.

This would have worked with `loss, win = 0, 0`, as you have a tuple of length 2 on the right.

Also, `loss = win = 0` (called a chained assignment) would be equivalent,  in cases where your value is immutable, to:

```
loss = 0
win = 0
```

Note that, as @chepner justly noted in the comments, using this syntax can lead to unexpected effects if you have a mutable object, as both `a` and `b` refer to the same object:

```
a = b = []
a.append(1)
print(b)
# [1]
```

So, in this case (and in general, if you want to be safe), you can write a single assignment on each line:

```
a = []
b = []
```

Comment: I would strong recommend avoiding chained assignment. Separate assignments will almost always be clearer, and chained assignments involving  mutable values will probably not do what you expect. `a = b = []` is not equivalent to `a = []; b = []`.

Comment: Maybe put more strongly, `a = b = c` and `a = c; b = c` are only equivalent if `c` is immutable and side-effect-free.

Comment: @chepner That's right, I'll add the warning in the answer.

Comment: not essential, but you might note explictely, that `a, b = [], []` is also a safe alternative to `a = b = []`

Answer (score -1):

```
loss = win = 0
```

or

```
loss, win = 0, 0
```

or

```
loss = 0 
win = 0
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no such thing as a switch statement in Python, so that whole syntax is incorrect.

Comment: That's my own function

Comment: The *syntax* is fine; the only objection would be if the name `switch` isn't bound to a callable value. I don't see any reason why you would assume this was an attempt to use a switch-like statement.